# Conditional probability independent of one variable

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X,Y$ and $Z$ be Borel spaces (that is, Borel subsets of Polish spaces) and let $\mathcal P(X)$ denote the Borel space of all Borel probability measures on $X$. For a product measure $P\in \mathcal P(X\times Y\times Z)$ let $\kappa:X\times Y\to\mathcal P(Z)$ be a regular conditional probability on $Z$ given $X\times Y$. We say that the measure $P$ is good if there exists a version of $\kappa$ that does not depend on $X$. Is that true that the set of all good measures if a Borel subset of $\mathcal P(X\times Y\times Z)$?

**Edit:** previous solution attempt is deleted as it appeared to be incorrect. At the same time, I hope a similar idea would still work. That is, we can find a countable set of conditions on $P$, each being measurable, so that $P$ is good iff it satisfies all these conditions. For example, maybe we can construct a countable system of function $f_i$ (e.g. independent of $x\in X$) such that some condition with $\int f_i \mathrm dP$ is the desired one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure any measure satisfying (1) is good, but I'm not sure about how your argument for measures satsfying (1) being measurable works. I will think some more about it.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: do you mean, that if 
$$
  P(A_i\times B_j \times C_k) = P_{XZ}(A_i\times C_k)\cdot P_Y(B_j)
$$
for all $i,j,k$ then $(1)$ may still fail to hold?

Comment: I rather think the argument is incomplete. But I believe the assertion may fail if the countable generators do not come from a $\pi$-system, which you could of course assume without loss of generality. But I do not see how exactly you would use (1) to define the set in question.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: thanks for the point regarding $\pi$-classes - I've found the statement in Kalleneberg. I've provided an extended argument on why all measures satisfying $(1)$ form a Borel set, is it correct? Could you suggest now how to show that any measure satisfying $(1)$ is good?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: I have found some kind of a similar statement that I may need in the first (1997) edition of Kallenberg, Proposition 5.13 (conditional independence and randomization). Is that something you've meant?

Comment: Yes, your proof seems to be correct. To see that (1) implies the good measure property one can rewrite the problem with kernels in a way that seems to "obviously" work. Verifying it may take some tricky applications of Fubini's theorem though. But I will post the sketch in the afternoon.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: thanks!

Comment: Here an idea that might work: Choose a countable $\pi$-system generating the $\sigma$-algebra on $Z$ and look at measures such that conditional probabilities for eleemtns in this system with respect to $X$ and with respect to $X\times Y$ are equal almost surely.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: I will try this. What about [continuing this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14943/discussion-between-ilya-and-michael-greinecker).

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: similarly, I can consider two $\pi$-generators on $X$ and $Z$ and just require the conditional independence condition to hold.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on a previous version of the question.

Let $P$ be a measure on $X\times Y\times Z$ satisfying (1). We want to show that $P$ is good.

Let ${\bf 1}$ be a probability space with a single element. We can identify a measure with a kernel with domain ${\bf 1}$.  We can also identify measurable functions with Dirac-measure-valued kernels and we can construct kernels $(\kappa_i)_i$ as pointwise stochastically independent products of kernels $\kappa_i$. Also, we can compose kernels in a natural way. Most of these things are formulated in the theory of the [category of probabilistic mappings](http://www.fuw.edu.pl/~kostecki/scans/lawvere1962.pdf).

In particular, since $P$ satisfies (1). we can treat the marginals $P_{XZ}$ and $P_Y$ as kernels and have $P=(P_{XZ},P_Y)$. Let $C:X\to\Delta(Y)$ be a regular conditional probability of (1). One can then rewrite the kernel $P_{XZ}$. There is a kernel $I$ from $X$ to $\Delta(X\times X)$ given by $I(x)=(x,x)$ and then a kernel $(I_X,C)$ from $X\times X$ to $\Delta(X\times Z)$ with $I_X$ the identity on $X$. So 
$$P_{XY}=(I_X,C)\circ I\circ P_X.$$ We can then write $\kappa$ as 
$$\kappa=\pi_Z\circ (I_X,C)\circ I,$$ which is clearly independent of $Y$. I'm pretty sure this form of reasoning by abstract nonsense is correct, but it might be hard to translate it in a conventional proof.

---

But a good measure may not give rise to the marginals $P_{XZ}$ and $P_Y$ being independent. A simple example is the uniform distribution on the diagonal of the unit cube $D=\{(x,x,x):x\in[0,1]\}$. One can write the regular conditional probability as a function of only the first coordinate, but the measures are not independent.

Comment: I'll check this out now. While waiting for your answer, one thought came to my mind. The original definition of the good measure is equivalent under permutation of spaces: e.g. let's call a good measure the one whose RCP on $Z$ given $X\times Y$ is independent of the $x$-variable. In such case, $(1)$ takes form $P(ABC) = P_X(A)P_{YZ}(BC)$. At the same time, let us consider a good measure $P = Q\otimes \kappa$ where $\kappa$ depends only on $y$. 
$$
  P(ABC) = \int_{AB}\kappa(y)Q(dx\times dy).
$$
Is that really $P_X(A)P_{YZ}(BC)$?

Comment: @Ilya If the kernel depends only on $y$, when calculating the product integral, the function is constant in $x$ and hence by integrating out over $A$ you are simply getting $P(A)$ as a constant factor.

Comment: But if $Q = P_X\otimes \lambda$ then we get
$$
  \int_{AB}\kappa(C|y)Q(dx\times dy) = \int_A\left(\int_B\kappa(C|y)\lambda(dy|x)\right)P_X(dx)
$$
and the function in brackets certainly does depend on $x$, so it does not seem we can get out $P_X(A)$ easily. Maybe I am missing something, I have not work with that for a while. Perhaps, you get some reference?

Comment: @Ilya Come to think of it, I think I have an example that good measures may fail to satisfy (1). Take $X=Y=Z=[0,1]$ and let $P$ be the uniform distribution on the diagonal $\{(x,x,x):x\in[0,1]\}$. Then we can write the conditional probability on $Z$ given $X\times Y$ clearly as a function of $X$, yet $P_{XZ}$ and $P_Y$ are clearly not independent.

Comment: Yeah, that's something that bothered me. Perhaps you can put this in your answer to show that my previous approach would not work. At the same time, the original question still stays open.